# WordPress: Archive for taxonomy and specific custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy (topic) which I use for more than one custom post type.
Let's say the taxonomy is "genre". Now I have custom post types like books, movies, games, songs and so on.

Now I use the taxonomy archive (taxonomy-genre.php) to show an overview of all custom post types with a specific taxonomy like "science fiction".

What I'm missing is an archive page for the taxonomy of a single custom post type.
For example all movies with the taxonomy "science fiction".

Is there a solution for that? I need to link to this archive page.

Comment: For custom taxonomy archive page go to https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/creating-wordpress-custom-taxonomy-archives/ and for custom post type archive page go to https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/creating-wordpress-custom-post-archives/ sites.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a combination of both archive types. I couldn't see how this will be possible with these two links :(

Comment: You have to use custom post type archive page and this template for identifying taxonomy you have use wp_query using custom taxonomy.